# indexOf() function always return zero even have the same string

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a variable in javascript

```
var hidden = "class_code,other";
```

then I have ajax which returning value

```
$.ajax({
type: "post",
data: $("#myform").serialize,
success: function(data){
    if(hidden.indexOf(data)){
    //mycode here
 }
}
});
```

but it doesn't work, so I try to use `alert()` to print the `hidden.indexOf(data)` and it always returns **0**, so I try to alert the data and it's returning `"class_code"`.

Why my script doesn't work even the hidden var is contains the data?

Comment: It is working. The index position of where 'class_code' starts is 0. What were you expecting?

Comment: zero doesn't mean it's not work, zero tell you the position of your "data" variable in "hidden" variable.

Comment: We don't know what data you are receiving, try this in your success function `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))` and check the console.
You might have to use some field inside your returned data and not the data object itself.

Comment: RTFM ~ [*"Note that '0' doesn't evaluate to true and '-1' doesn't evaluate to false"*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf#Checking_occurrences)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`indexOf` returns the position where the matching string begins. Since `class_code` is at the beginning of `class_code,other`, this is `0`. When the string isn't found, it returns `-1`. The correct way to test if the string is found is with:

```
if (hidden.indexOf(data) != -1)
```

Comment: Ohh thanks, i dont know about that,i was thingking that 0 is false

Comment: Obviously. This is a common mistake with `indexOf`.

Answer (score 1):

[.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) is working - the string `"class_code"` starts at the 0th index of the string `"class_code,other"`.  If the string was not contained, it would return `-1`

Comment: Put this in your answer https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf